# PostgreSQL C++ Api getting error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E8

Tags: c#, c++, postgresql, winapi, libpq

I try [libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/) and [pg_bulkload](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000261) for C++ data bulk loader from my Simple C# App.
Because this two libs on my PC not  finally supported.
I now , new create simple DLL project,with native PostgreSQL libpq methods.

CPPApp.h

```
#pragma once  

#ifdef CPPAPP_EXPORTS
#define CPPAPP_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPPAPP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  

#include "libpq-fe.h"

extern CPPAPP_API PGconn* conn;

#ifdef __cplusplus
CPPAPP_API extern "C" {
#endif  

    void OpenDb(const char* connStr);

    void CloseDb(void);

    int getVersion(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

CPPApp.cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "CPPApp.h" 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

CPPAPP_API PGconn* conn = nullptr;

void OpenDb(const char* connStr)
{
    conn = PQconnectdb(connStr);

    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        cout << "Connection to database failed." << endl;
        CloseDb();
    }

    cout << "Connection to database - OK" << endl;

}

void CloseDb(void)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
}

int getVersion(void)
{
    int version = PQserverVersion(conn);

    cout << "PostgreSQL version is " << version << endl;

    return version;
}
```

**Error: error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E8**

Can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically happens when you try to link with a DLL (that would be `libpq.dll` in this case) instead of a library (`libpq.lib`).

Assuming you downloaded PostgreSQL for Windows from [enterprisedb pre-compiled binaries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows), there's a `lib` directory inside the installation directory with `libpq.lib`. That's the file you want to indicate as an external library to your Visual Studio project.

Comment: Ok!,thx I solved this error.Next error - "error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"? Thx for answ.